# Python Raise Exception and Return Default Value

Tags: python

I'm writing a function using geopy's GoogleV3 to get addresses from longitudes and latitudes:

```
from retrying import retry
@retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=500, wait_exponential_max=4000, stop_max_attempt_number=5)
def get_address(lat, lon):
    state = 'unknown'
    country = 'unknown'
    geo = GoogleV3(api_key='my-secret-api-key')
    location = geo.reverse((lat, lon), timeout=10, exactly_one=True)
    if location == None:
        raise ValueError('a valid location for %d, %d is not found' % (lat, lon))
    for item in location.raw['address_components']:
        if u'administrative_area_level_1' in item[u'types']:
            state = item['short_name']
        if u'country' in item[u'types']:
            country = item['long_name']
    return state, country
```

The `retrying` decorator here will automatically retry on exceptions. Here I want to raise an exception to indicate that the `lon` and `lat` given is not valid, and at the same time return `country` and `state` both as 'unknown'. I'd like to know if there's a way to do so in Python.

Comment: Even if you could do that, how would the calling code deal with it?  If you're returning "unknown" as the value, then that itself should be the indication that the value is invalid (i.e., the calling code should check for "unknown").

Comment: Returning a value means, "This algorithm has completed normally. Here is the result." Raising an exception means, "Something happened that this algorithm cannot deal with: here is what it is." These are mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: @J Freebird hi, can you please tell me how and where you buy and get your my-secret-google-api? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  On any given call, a function can either raise an exception, or it can return a value.  It can't do both.